# Capture snapshot from camera with swift inside ARSCNview

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have been using self.sceneview.session.currentframe.capturedimage and sceneview.Snapshot() for capturing images from ARSCNview, However the images I captured from these methods blurred due to the fixed focus of ARSCNview.

So I am wondering if there is any method to capture quality snapshot from UIview/Camera inside the ARSCNview class. I am new to swift development and I would highly appreciate any help regarding this issue.

```
class ar:ARSCNview{
    func classificationcomphandler(){
        if(needtocapturescreen)
            //code to capture snapshotfrom camera and return image(UI view)
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can find out how to take a screenshot from ARKit-Example-by-Apple (https://github.com/gao0122/ARKit-Example-by-Apple) with the function "takeScreenshot()"

Comment: I've tried it but it only produces blurred images because it uses ARsceneView fixed focused frames. I want to use the captured image for ocr later so blurred images are not useful.

Comment: That is a limitation from Apple's side. you can go around that, but as it is a private api, your app will be rejected. see answers at: https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/761r2u/is_it_just_me_or_do_all_arkit_apps_have_blurry/ and from Rickster on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46676012/how-to-improve-camera-quality-in-arkit

Comment: I tried the method Reddit user afranke suggested using setFocusModeLocked() function. However, it does not affect the lens focus when it used with ARSCNview.